# Подчеркнуть каждый символ в теге label

Tags: html, label

Всем привет! У меня есть регистрация на сайте, и выглядит она следующим образом:

[image]

Дело в том, что во время ввода пароля, да как и других полей, можно ошибиться и вписать символ пробела " " и не заметить его.

**Вопрос**: можно ли как-то подчеркнуть **каждый** символ, который записан в теге **label**? (На скрине показано, там есть два пробела.)

P.S. 1: Сплошное подчёркивание - не вариант.
P.S. 2: Не дать ввести пробел - не вариант.
P.S. 3: Каждый символ заключить в отдельный тег **label** и поставить ему подчёркивание - на крайний случай.

Comment: Самый лучший вариант - написать CSS стиль для label. 
Либо воспользоваться Вашим, третьим вариантом.

Почитайте немного инфы вот тут: http://artgorbunov.ru/bb/soviet/20120510/

Comment: МаринаВоин, я не нашёл свойства, благодаря которому подчёркивание не сплошное, а для каждого символа.

Comment: http://artgorbunov.ru/bb/soviet/20120510/
Но это небольшой мануал, и там все будет зависеть от шрифта, ширины символа. Так что более точную инфу дать не смогу, так как не верстальщик.

Comment: Кстати, вопрос касаемо Вашей темы: http://hashcode.ru/questions/120720/%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B2-css

Comment: МаринаВоин, к сожалению, не нашёл на этом сайте решения моей проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Каждый символ оберните в `<span>` - это и будет самое верное решение:

```
label span {
    border-bottom: 1px aqua solid;
}

<label>
<span>s</span><span>y</span><span>m</span><span> </span><span>b</span><span>o</span><span>l</span>
</label>
```

Но я вижу, у вас на сайте есть `javascript`, обернуть все символы, например, так:

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    var result = $('input').val()
    ,   view = '';

    for(var i=0; i < result.length; i++) {
        view += "<span>"+result[i].replace(" ", "&nbsp;")+"</span>";
    }

    $('#view').html(view);
});
```

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/rmww8Lws/1/

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - нарисовать свой фонт. Вернее, отредактировать какой-нибудь